# How could I define a trigger which fires only when a particular column is updated to a certain value?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Please suppose you have an Oracle table called `GOOFY`.  This table has a column called `MINNIE`.
I would like to write a trigger which fires only when the `MINNIE` column is updated to `'RUNNING'` value.
So, I have to write something as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_FIRST_SERIOUS_TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE
ON GOOFY
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (UPPER(TRIM(:NEW.MINNIE)) = 'RUNNING')
```

... but I receive the following Oracle error:

```
ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause
```

By changing the heading of the trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_FIRST_SERIOUS_TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE
ON GOOFY
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
WHEN (UPPER(TRIM(:NEW.MINNIE)) = 'RUNNING')
```

... I receive the following Oracle error:

```
ORA-04077: WHEN clause cannot be used with table level triggers
```

What's wrong with my trigger?

Thank you very much for having considered my request.

Comment: When you reference `NEW` in the `where` clause of a row-level trigger, prependig colon should not be specified. So it will simply be `UPPER(TRIM(NEW.MINNIE)) = 'RUNNING'`. Moreover, there is really no need for `REFERENCING` clause in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t;
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (
  3       x NUMBER,
  4       y NUMBER,
  5       z NUMBER
  6    );
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR replace TRIGGER t_trigger
  2    AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON t
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4    WHEN ( ( NEW.x <> OLD.x
  5              OR ( NEW.x IS NULL
  6                   AND OLD.x IS NOT NULL )
  7              OR ( NEW.x IS NOT NULL
  8                   AND OLD.x IS NULL ) )
  9            OR ( NEW.y <> OLD.y
 10                  OR ( NEW.y IS NULL
 11                       AND OLD.y IS NOT NULL )
 12                  OR ( NEW.y IS NOT NULL
 13                       AND OLD.y IS NULL ) ) )
 14  BEGIN
 15      dbms_output.Put_line('Trigger is fired');
 16  END;
 17
 18  /
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t
  2  VALUES      ( 0,
  3               0,
  4               0 );
SQL>
SQL> SET feedback OFF;
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET    x = 0;
SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET    x = 1;
Trigger is fired
SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET    x = NULL;
Trigger is fired
SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET    x = 1;
Trigger is fired
SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET    x = 1;
SQL>
```

So, simply use **NEW**